# How can I issue parallel commands to remote nodes with different arguments?

Tags: ssh, parallelism, pdsh

I need to execute an application in parallel on multiple Ubuntu servers while supplying different arguments for different servers. I tried to google it, but could not get to the possible solution. I even experimented with ssh/pdsh/parallel, but without success.

To explain the scenario further, here is a non-working example (with `pdsh`) where `script.sh` should be executed on all 3 servers in parallel but with different arguments. FYI, I already have public/private ssh-key (password-free login) in place.

```
pdsh -w server1,server2,server3 -l username script.sh args
```

Where `args` should be 1 for server1, 2 for server2 etc.

I would appreciate if someone can help me achieve this, either using `pdsh` or some other tool available in Ubuntu.

Comment: is key based auth there ?

Comment: If you are talking about ssh public/private key auth, then yes its there.

Comment: have you tested with `parallel ` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GNU version of parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__using_remote_computers)

For example, to call `echo` with the arguments `1` through `10`, dispatching each `echo` command to one of `server.example.com` or `server2.example.net`:

```
seq 10 | parallel --sshlogin server.example.com,server2.example.net echo
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul for your suggestion, but it will not work for me. I need to provide different arguments to different servers, which is not possible in the provided example. After receiving a reply on other forum, I am planning to write a script to issue these requests serially in background.

Comment: `echo arg1 arg2 | parallel --sshlogin server.example.com,server2.example.net --colsep ' ' echo {1} {2}`

Comment: also watch video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: @Sachin Each input line is passed as an argument to a different server (or, if there are more arguments than servers, several commands will be executed on the same server).

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Gilles for your help. From the link of "GNU version of parallel", it seems that parallel tries to execute command on each core on remote node. Instead of this, I just want to have a single instance of application per remote node irrespective of number of cores available. For now, a script issuing jobs in a loop over servers and putting jobs in background (using pdsh) is working for me.